# Why is the method receiver not required to be a pointer when implementing sort.Interface for golang types?

Tags: go

I am reading the docs for the [sort](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/) stdlib package and the sample code reads like this:

```
type ByAge []Person

func (a ByAge) Len() int           { return len(a) }
func (a ByAge) Swap(i, j int)      { a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i] }
func (a ByAge) Less(i, j int) bool { return a[i].Age < a[j].Age }
```

As I've learnt, function that mutate a type `T` needs to use `*T` as its method receiver.
In the case of `Len`, `Swap` and `Less` why does it work ? Or am I misunderstanding the difference between using `T` vs `*T` as method receivers ?

Comment: A slice is a reference type. The underlying array is always passed by reference.

Comment: So if I defined my own struct, that is a value type & would need *T for mutating methods. Ok, that is clear.

Comment: Yes. That sounds about right.

Comment: But wait, this 2nd example in this [snippet](http://play.golang.org/p/Att-AalCzG) is not mutating.

Comment: That second example shows where you do need a pointer. Append might need to allocate more storage, and when it does the original array is no longer valid. This can't be written back to the slice without a pointer receiver.

Comment: @JimB Aha. So if I am just sorting, no new memory allocation is needed. I am sorting in place, thus T as a method receiver is sufficient (but only if T is a reference type). I can only count maps and slices as reference types. There aren't any others, right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go has three reference types:

- map
- slice
- channel

Every instance of these types holds a pointer to the actual data internally. This means that
when you pass a value of one of these types the value is **copied** like every other value but the 
internal pointer still points to the same value.

Quick example ([run on play](http://play.golang.org/p/cbj_mogFLb)):

```
func dumpFirst(s []int) {
    fmt.Printf("address of slice var: %p, address of element: %p\n", &s, &s[0])
}

s1 := []int{1, 2, 3}
s2 := s1

dumpFirst(s1)
dumpFirst(s2)
```

will print something like:

```
address of slice var: 0x1052e110, address of element: 0x1052e100
address of slice var: 0x1052e120, address of element: 0x1052e100
```

You can see: the address of the slice variable changes but the address of the first element in that slice remains the same.

Comment: I would say that a pointer is also a "reference type". Also, slice is more complicated: it combines a pointer with a length and capacity, and the latter two are "by value".

Comment: For the sake of this question it does not matter what else the slice value that is copied contains. The point is that it holds a pointer to the actual data. *Everything* of a slice value is *copied*. The pointer, the capacity and the length. The trick is that the pointer still points to the same address.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a minor epiphany regarding this exact same question.

As has already been explained, a typed slice (*not* a pointer to a slice) can implement the `sort.Interface` interface; part of the reason for this is that, even though the slice is being copied, one of its fields is a pointer to an array, so any modification of that backing array will be reflected in the original slice.

Normally, though, this isn't enough of a justification for a bare slice to be an acceptable receiver. It's generally incorrect to try to modify a struct as a receiver of a method, because any `append()` calls will change the slice *copy*'s length without modifying the original slice's headers. Slice modification may even trigger the initialization of a new backing array, completely disconnecting the copied receiver from the original slice.

By the very nature of sorting, however, this isn't a problem in the `sort.Sort` case. The only array-modifying operation it exercises is `Swap`, meaning the array's required memory will remain the same, so the slice will not change size, and therefore there will be no changes to the slice's actual values (starting index, length, and array pointer).

I'm sure this was obvious to a lot of people, but it just dawned on me, and I thought it might be useful to others wondering why `sort` plays nicely with bare slices.